# Best Cheap NAS from eBay with Support for LFF

Tags: hard-disk, server, nas

so browsing through Amazon I find NAS's that seem to be the right fit. This one for instance seems good: [The Synology 12 bay](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NF987TP)

But the price is wayyyyyy too much ($1500 at the time of writing this). I've been buying HP Proliant G8s for virtualization so I'm used to getting really good equipment for very cheap (e.g. 32 core 100gb ram servers for under $300).

I have been searching eBay for a similar NAS solution (SAS, 10GbE, LPMI, dual processors/power supplies nice to haves). However, I'm unsure where/how I can find servers/NASes that support huge LFF drives. I would like to fill up a 12 bay with 16TB Exos but I can't find any with RAID controllers that support large hard drives.

Does anyone know how I can find a cheap NAS that supports high TB count LFF HDs?